# filtering dataset on multiple ACCESS databases to optimize results

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dataset

I have the following c# code to filter at present data while connecting to multiple MS access database Tables. This works fine but as the Dataset ds is too huge for loop takes forever to return checking each row calling another mdb database table. Is there a way to optimize this to delete the rows based on the column filters.

```
string ABCACCESSDataSource = @"c:\websites\abc.mdb";
string XYZACCESSDataSource = @"c:\websites\xyz.mdb";

private void dataviewTable()
{
        OleDbConnection Conn = DatabaseCommands.openDBConnection(ABCACCESSDataSource, this);
        string query1 = select column1, column2, column3 from ABCTable where column2 = 'hello' order by column1;
        Dataview dv; 
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query1, Conn);

        DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "ABCTable");

         foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["ABCTable"].Rows)
          checkValue = dr["ABCTable"].ToString();
                        {
                        resultvalue = getvalue(checkValue);
                        if(resultvalue == "unavailable")
                        {
                            dr.delete();
                        }

             dv = ds.Tables["ABCTable"].DefaultView;    
}    

private string getvalue(string checkValuepassed)    
{
        OleDbConnection Conn2 = DatabaseCommands.openDBConnection(XYZACCESSDataSource, this);
        string query2 = select columnX from XYZTable where columnY = 'test' AND columnZ = '" + checkValuepassed +"'" ;;

        OleDbDataAdapter da2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(query2, Conn2);
        ds2 = new DataSet();
                        da2.Fill(ds2);
                        resultVal = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() ;

                        return resultVal;
}
```

Comment: Are the column names really Column1, Column2, etc..because I notice that you are check for Column Names = 'hello' what's the table structure look like.. I would suggest reading / googling how to use OLEDB with Access Database this looks a bit sloppy..

Comment: column names are like ID, name, score, etc...This is not sloppy and it works completely fine.Its just the table results are too huge and I m trying to optimize this.

Comment: Then change your Question to Depict that.. it will make it easier for someone to give you a more reasonable answer in my Opinion

Comment: The problem is not tables too big.  5000 rows is small.  The problem is multiple calls to the DB.

Comment: I know its because of multiple calls to the DB but I can't avoid as the results I get from first DB will be filtered by the checking each column value passed to second DB and it needs to check for each row which takes too much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a single value then putting it in Table to retrieve the values is slow.

But retrieve the values once.

```
string query2 = select columnZ, columnX from XYZTable where columnY = 'test' ;;

Dictionary<string, string> table2Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

table2Dict.add(columnZ, columnX);

colZvalue = table2Dict[checkValuepassed];
```

Another way to look at this is not loop the ABC.
Just loop XYZ and issue delete commands to ABC.
If the record is not there it will delete nothing. 
And batch up in groups of like 10-100.
There will be sweet spot.
Delete [XYX] where [ABCTable] in (..,..,..);

Comment: So to fill  the table2 in the code above , I need do a for loop and add each item key and value to it ?

Comment: I tried this but what I get when I passed where ColumnY = 'test' is around 9000 rows and I need to get that one row where checkValuePassed is passed.

Comment: You are not following.  The whole idea is to get 9000 rows and put them in a dictionary.  You only touch table XYZ ONCE.  Then you use table2Dict[checkValuepassed];

Comment: Thank you Blam and everyone I got this worked out as Blam Mentioned about using Dictionary and store values at once ..!!

Answer (score 0):

How big is the second database (XYZ) ? 
If it fits in memory, you can first select all rows from it (without any columnZ = ...) in a Dictionairy and then doing only memory operations in getvalue(..), thus saving a lot of OleDb queries.

Comment: Around 5000 rows in each table !! Thanks for suggestion. I will try this